# Shellshock Bash bug on mobile systems

Tags: android, unix, shellshock

Does the [bug](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271) in Bash affect Android or iOS mobile systems?

Comment: I believe jailbroken iOS devices can be affected. For instance, the [Cydia app store](https://cydia.saurik.com/) for jailbroken devices installs Bash and other BSD utilities (reference needed). However since you already disable all of the system safeguards and run untrusted software when jailbreaking or rooting, there are other entry points for malware that you already need to take into account.

Comment: I ran the official test-script `env x='(){ :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "this is a test"` via the app ScriptManager on my Sony XPERIA, it told me `env is not defined`. So i guess no; but still no proof.

Comment: Note that the error you get only indicates that there is no method called `env` for modifying the environment of your shell called ScriptManager, not that no application on your system relies on Bash and can incidentally or voluntarily let untrusted principals enter commands with a custom environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not out-of-the-box. I know of no Android or iOS device running a bash shell. Some people might, on their rooted devices, but that will be only a few.

Comment: Isn't /bin/sh based on bash and contain the vulnerability?  Because /bin/sh exists on Android.

Comment: @raz `/bin/sh` is not necessarily the same as bash (though it can be an alias for bash in some cases). In the case of Android, it almost certainly isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I have run the official test script on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and it indicates it is vulnerable. This device was just out of the box and has not been rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Some Aftermarket Android ROMs like CM are vulnerable, because they have the bash shell in their ROMs integrated. CM [fixed](https://twitter.com/CyanogenMod/status/515255238509359104) their Nightlies. I tried the official test script on my Android Devices (all with Custom ROMs) and all were vulnerable.